# Avoid nested for loops when filling 2D array

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, for-loop, set

I have a matrix of `n by n` shape to fill  with `n=60,000`

The values of the matrix are binary : 0 or 1.

**Under the constraint :**

`matrix_to_fill[i,j]=matrix_to_fill[j,i]= 1.0` if only if

```
'bool(set(elements[i]) @ set(elements[j])) == True'
```

**What l have tried :**

```
'matrix_to_fill=np.zeros(n,n) # it is a symmetric matrix : 

 for i in np.arange(n):

        for j in np.arange(n):
           
            if i==j:  # diagonal elements are set to zero

                break

            else:

                bool_value = bool(set(element[i]) & set(element[j]))

                if bool_value:
                        matrix_to_fill[i][j]=1.0
                        matrix_to_fill[j][i] = 1.0'
```

**What is wrong ?**

Too heavy, it takes a long time. It is still running for more than 1 hour

Any cue, to avoid the nested loop and reduce the computational time ?

Comment: what is `element`?

Comment: It in a numpy array composed of integer values

Comment: what is its shape?

Comment: it has no shape, it is a list <class 'list'>,  number of values in  element[i] and  element[j] is different

Comment: Is it clear @warped ?